# Can I insert a value into index 6 of an array that has a length of only 4?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Is that possible? Say there is an array `[3, 4]` and I want to insert 5 at index 3 to get `[3, 4, null, 5]`, is there a utility to accomplish this?

Comment: You can just insert any value at any index you like. If you skip indices, they will be considered holes in a sparse array, so you'll get `undefined` when accessing them. If you don't want holes and actually want `null`, then just use a loop to fill values until you get to the index you want.

Comment: Undefined is satisfactory too.

Comment: The Array doesn't actually have the value `undefined`. It's just giving you the default value you get when a property doesn't exist. This can have an effect on when you use iterator methods like `.forEach()` and others which skip holes in the Array. So it depends on if you are actually OK with holes or not.

Comment: Hmm - I think I should be okay as long as it can ascertain the intended index and won't mistake an element inserted at index 4 for index 2.

Comment: Why not try it and see? `var a = [3,4]; a[3] = 5; console.log(a);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's called a "sparse" array.

```
var ary = [];

ary[5] = 1;

console.log(ary.length); // 6
console.log(ary); // [undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,1]
```

Comment: That won't give the result described in the question.

Comment: Ah, deceptive. When I console.log the array, I just get `[ 5: 1 ]`, but when I log the length, it gives me 6, so it seems it is working.

Comment: @squint: undefined behaves a lot like null, and is usable in the same way for just about any useful purpose.

Comment: @realisation: Depending on your browser, the console log of the array will give you something like [5 x undefined, 1]. That's just a shorthand representation of the array, which will be what I show above. The point is, if you iterate through the array it will represent undefined for indices 0 through 4 and 1 for index 5.